How to perform batch processing of images through Google Translate
I have a bunch of images with text in another language. How do I translate all of them at once using Google Translate? I could do it manually one-by-one, but that would take too long and be tedious.
For more detail, this question has already been asked in this post, and the top answer is "this is impossible", while the second answer does not work anymore after Google changed their API. I would love to post my answer to the existing question, but I do not have sufficient reputation and I'm not going to game the system just to answer one question. I read through the code of conduct, and do not see any clauses prohibiting or discouraging this.
People have tried using the Google Cloud Translate library in Python, which used to work, but the specific function translate.Client().translate_image that allowed image translation through the API is no longer available.

I have a working solution using AutoHotkey V2.
This script is more simple, and does the bare minimum. If anything fails to load, it may enter an undesirable state.
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

urlGT:="https://translate.google.com/?sl=ja&tl=en&op=images"    ; adjust as necessary for different languages.
;                                                                 This example is for Japanese to English
fpImageList:="lists\gallery1.txt"                               ; relative or absolute path to `n, `r`n, or `n`r delimited text file
;                                                                 containing a list of filepaths. Leading and trailing quotation marks will
;                                                                 be trimmed, so don't worry about that.

msSleep1:=1000                                                  ; Milliseconds to wait for Google Translate to load
msSleep2:=2000                                                  ; Milliseconds to wait for translation to complete

strFps := FileRead(fpImageList)
arrFps := StrSplit(strFps, "`n")

Run(urlGT), Sleep(msSleep1)                                     ; Open Google Translate

for strFp in arrFps {
    strFp:=Trim(strFp,"`r`n`"")
    Send("{Enter}"), Sleep(100), Send("{Enter}"), Sleep(100)    ; Open file
    Send(strFp), Send("{Enter}"), Sleep(msSleep2)               ; Translate
    Send("+{Tab}"), Sleep(50), Send("+{Tab}"), Sleep(50)        ; Select 'download translation' button
    Send("{Enter}"), Sleep(500)                                 ; Save file
    Send("!{Left}"), Sleep(msSleep1)                            ; Go back to the previous page (may need to be changed depending on browser)
}
MsgBox("Translation is complete")

This next one has some error checking and will retry a pre-set number of times if anything fails. It will also move the file from the downloads folder into a directory adjacent from the source image, e.g. if the source image was "\images\image.jpg", the translated image will go into "\images-English\image.jpg". The suffix can be changed via TargetSuffix
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0

urlGT:="https://translate.google.com/?sl=ja&tl=en&op=images"    ; adjust as necessary for different languages.
;                                                                 This example is for Japanese to English
fpImageList:="lists\gallery1.txt"                               ; relative or absolute path to `n, `r`n, or `n`r delimited text file
;                                                                 containing a list of filepaths. Leading and trailing quotation marks will
;                                                                 be trimmed, so don't worry about that.

msSleepLoad:=2000                                               ; Milliseconds to wait for Google Translate to load
msSleepLoad2:=1000                                              ; Milliseconds to wait for Google Translate to render
msSleepTL:=3000                                                 ; Milliseconds to wait for translation to complete
msSleepDL:=1000                                                 ; Milliseconds to wait for download to complete
msSleepStdLong:=300
msSleepStdShort:=100

numTries:=5                                                     ; Number of times to retry if an image fails
secWait:=5                                                      ; Seconds to wait before retrying

TargetSuffix:="English"                                         ; Places resulting images in a version of the source directory with this text added

A_Downloads:=RegExReplace(A_Desktop, "Desktop$", "Downloads")   ; Modify this if your default downloads directory is not in the same directory as your default desktop folder

strFps := FileRead(fpImageList)
arrFps := StrSplit(strFps, "`n")

Run(urlGT)
OpenGT

for strFp in arrFps {
    strFp:=Trim(strFp,"`r`n`"")
    fileName := StrSplit(strFp, "\").Pop()
    fpTargetDir := RegExReplace(strFp, "\\" fileName "$","") "-" TargetSuffix
    fpTargetDL := A_Downloads "\" fileName
    fpTarget := fpTargetDir "\" fileName
    
    if FileExist(fpTarget)="" {
        TranslateRun(strFp)
        n:=0
        While (!FileDLMove(strFp,fpTargetDir,fpTargetDL,fpTarget))&&n<numTries{
            Run(urlGT)
            OpenGT
            TranslateRun(strFp)
            n+=1
        }
        Send("!{Left}")                                         ; Go back to the previous page (may need to be changed depending on browser)
        OpenGT
    }
}
MsgBox("Translation is complete")

OpenGT(){                                                       ; Open Google Translate
    n:=0
    While (!WinWaitActive("Google Translate",,msSleepLoad/1000))&&(n<numTries){
        Run(urlGT)
        n+=1
    }
    Sleep(msSleepLoad2)
    Send("{Enter}"), Sleep(msSleepStdLong), Send("{Enter}")
}

TranslateRun(strFp){
    n:=0
    While (!WinWaitActive("Open",,secWait))&&(n<numTries){      ; Open file dialog
        Send("{Esc}"), Sleep(msSleepStdShort), Send("{Esc}")
        Run(urlGT)
        OpenGT
        n+=1
    }
    if !(WinGetTitle("A")=="Open"){
        MsgBox("Failed to open file dialog")
        ExitApp
    }
    ControlSetText(strFp,"Edit1")
    Send("{Enter}"), Sleep(msSleepTL)                           ; Translate
    
    Send("+{Tab}"), Sleep(msSleepStdShort)
    Send("+{Tab}"), Sleep(msSleepStdShort)                      ; Select 'download translation' button
    Send("{Enter}"), Sleep(msSleepDL)                           ; Save file
}
FileDLMove(strFp,fpTargetDir,fpTargetDL,fpTarget){
    try {
        If DirExist(fpTargetDir)=="" {
            DirCreate(fpTargetDir)
        }
        FileMove(fpTargetDL, fpTarget, 0)
        return true
    } catch {
        return false
    }
}

